# Authlogic OpenID integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, authlogic

I'm having difficulty getting OpenId authentication working with Authlogic.  It appears that the problem arose with changes to the open_id_authentication plugin.  From what I've read so far, one needs to switch from using gems to using plugins.

Here's what I done thus far to get Authlogic-OpenID integration working:

1. Removed relevant gems:

   - authlogic
   - authlogic-oid
   - rack-openid
   - ruby-openid *
   - Installed, configured, and started the authlogic sample application (http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example)--works as expected.  This required:
   - installing the authlogic (2.1.3) gem ($ sudo gem install authlogic)
   - adding a dependency (config.gem "authlogic") to the environment.rb file.
   - added migration to add open-id support to User model; ran migration; columns added as expected
   - made changes to the UsersController and UserSessionsController to use blocks to save each.
   - made changes to new user-sessions view to support open id (f.text_field :openid_identifier)
   - installed open_id_authentication plugin ($ script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/open_id_authentication.git)
   - installed the authlogic-oid plugin ($ script/plugin install git://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_openid.git)
   - installed the plugin ($ script/plugin install git://github.com/glebm/ruby-openid.git)
   - restarted mongrel (CTRL-C; $ script/server)

Mogrel failed to start, returning the following error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- rack/openid (MissingSourceFile)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/craibuc/NetBeansProjects/authlogic_example/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Users/craibuc/NetBeansProjects/authlogic_example/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/craibuc/NetBeansProjects/authlogic_example/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Users/craibuc/NetBeansProjects/authlogic_example/vendor/plugins/open_id_authentication/lib/open_id_authentication.rb:3
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/craibuc/NetBeansProjects/authlogic_example/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Users/craibuc/NetBeansProjects/authlogic_example/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/craibuc/NetBeansProjects/authlogic_example/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Users/craibuc/NetBeansProjects/authlogic_example/vendor/plugins/open_id_authentication/init.rb:5:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin.rb:146:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from /Users/craibuc/NetBeansProjects/authlogic_example/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin.rb:142:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin.rb:48:in `load'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:38:in `load_plugins'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `each'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `load_plugins'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:348:in `load_plugins'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:163:in `process'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /Users/craibuc/NetBeansProjects/authlogic_example/config/environment.rb:13
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/craibuc/NetBeansProjects/authlogic_example/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Users/craibuc/NetBeansProjects/authlogic_example/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/craibuc/NetBeansProjects/authlogic_example/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Users/craibuc/NetBeansProjects/authlogic_example/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:84
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

I suspect this is related the rack-openid gem, but as it was dependent upon the ruby-openid gem, it was removed when the ruby-openid gem was removed.  Perhaps this can be installed as a plugin.

Any assistance with this matter is greatly appreciated--I'm just about to give up on OpenId integration.

* ruby-openid (2.1.2) is installed at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8.  I'm not certain if this is affecting anything.  In any case, I'm not sure how to uninstall it or if I should.

** edit **

It appears that there are a number of gems in the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems directory that may be causing an issue:

- authlogic-oid (1.0.4)
- rack-openid (1.0.3)
- ruby-openid (2.1.7)

Questions:
 - why doesn't the gem list command list these gems?
 - Why doesn't the gem uninstall command remove these gems?

Answer (score 3):

i've got the same problem here just now, but fixed just installing the rack-openid gem.
I'll ask them to add rack-openid to the required libraries on documentation

Answer (score 3):

I went through the same hassles as you did.
Maybe you should just check this out, have got everything working:

http://github.com/shripadk/authlogic_openid_selector_example

This includes a stackoverflow like openid autoregistration too. I have hosted an example app on heroku for you to try out before checkout if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how things work on OSX, but in Linux if I install gems as a regular user they get put in my home directory, and if I install them using `sudo` they go into a system directory.

I've had permissions problems with gems as well, and had to explicitly set a `GEM_PATH` in my shell to get ruby to load gems from a specific location.

- Do those old gems show up if you run `sudo gem list`?
- Do you have gems installed in your home directory as well as in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8`?

**Edit**:

Ok, I'd fire up an `irb` session and see what happens when you `require` the gems explicitly.

```
$ irb
> require 'authlogic'
> require 'authlogic-oid'
...
```

**Edit:**

If the `authlogic-oid` gem is installed, and appears when you run `sudo gem list`, try starting `irb` as superuser. If you can then require `authlogic-oid`, you have a permissions problem: some or all of the gem files are readonly root.

If that doesn't work, you likely have a load path problem - ruby is confused about where to look for your installed gems. In that case, your `authlogic` gem is probably installed in a different location to your `authlogic-oid` gem.

Comment: sudo gem list does not enumerate these gems.

I have gems installed in three locations: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems, /craibuc/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems, and /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems.

Comment: Is uninstalling a gem as easy as deleting the gem's directory?

Comment: Yep, unless it's also installed executables elsewhere (as is the case with `rails` and `haml` for example)

Comment: To uninstall the gem, I decided to delete the directory, install the gem ($ sudo gem [gem name] install), then uninstall the gem ($ sudo gem [gem name] uninstall).  This appears to have removed the gem 'properly'.  I'll test the authlogic-openid integration tomorrow.

Comment: require 'authlogic' returned true.  require 'authlogic-oid' returned: no such file to load -- authlogic-oid

Comment: Updated answer with more ideas